# Avoid writing of NULL fields present in pyspark dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, etl, pyspark

I have a spark dataframe having the following entries

`column1 | column2
   "a"  |   "b"
   "x"  |   "c" 
   null |   "a"
   null |   "b"
    "x" |   null`

So when I convert it to a glue dynamic frame and write to an S3 bucket in json format the null values are also written.
I don't want to convert the null field to an empty string or number etc. Basically if a field value is null it should not be written. How can I avoid writing the null fields?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like to `.na.fill('')` default your values to empty string

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([("a",), ("b",), ("c",), (None,)], ['col'])
df.show()
+----+
| col|
+----+
|   a|
|   b|
|   c|
|null|
+----+

df.na.fill('').show()
+---+
|col|
+---+
|  a|
|  b|
|  c|
|   |
+---+
```

Comment: yaa. but i simply want to avoid writing that field. converting to zero will write 0 to col field which my application does not support

Comment: then fill it with an empty string @kmkhan

Comment: no formating of null data needs to be done. while writing they need to be avoided.

Comment: when you say avoid NULL you  meant to filter the entire row or just that value ?

Comment: just that value. not the entire row.

Comment: That is not possible as spark is not strict while reading the data but when it comes writing the data it will follow the schema and will output the data in the respective format with full schema @kmkhan

Comment: I found a way :). https://stackoverflow.com/a/62108077/8162018

Comment: @kmkhan It will again remove rows and not field which contradicts with what you are asking

Comment: say we have 2 columns x and y. Now 4 cases arise (null, null), (not null, null), (null, not null) and (not null, not null). If say we want the dataframe in 2nd case, run sql query as SELECT x FROM table WHERE (x IS NOT NULL) AND (y IS NULL). This way we get only the NOT NULL fields in the dataframe. I tested  the same and it works. So for this we need 3 queries(because null, null is skipped)